# Is $f(x,y) = x^2 - 2e^y$ concave or convex?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, convex-analysis

Is $f(x,y) = x^2 - 2e^y$ concave or convex?

My thought process is as such:

$f'(x,y)=2x - 2e^y$;

$f''(x,y)=2 - 2e^y$

Thus when $y<0$ ($2e^y<2$), $f''(x,y)<0 \implies f(x,y)$ is convex.

Likewise, when $y>0$, $f''(x,y)>0 \implies f(x,y)$ is concave.

But the answer says $f(x,y)$ is neither concave nor convex - why is that?

Comment: What is this second derivative of a multivariable function you’re calculating here?

Comment: Shouldn't it be $y < 0 \implies 2e^y < 2 \implies f''(x,y) > 0$?

Comment: @MohammadZuhairKhan, yes that was what I meant, y<0, sorry for the typo!

Answer (score 2):

The hessian is $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2e^{-y}\end{bmatrix}$. The eigenvalues are $2$ (positive) and $-2e^{-y}$ (negative). Hence it is indefinite.

If you fix $y$ and move along $x$, you trace out a convex path.

If you fix $x$ and move along $y$, you trace out a concave path.

It is like a saddle.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is a good example of a function with a [saddle point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saddle_point) at 0. Mind you, the expression $f^\prime$ is meaningless as the function depends on two variables, hence we need to take partial derivatives to gain any information. So, that is
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2x, \quad\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 2
$$
and
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = -2e^y, \quad \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2} = -2e^y
$$
This tells us that at the origin the second derivative is positive in the $x$ direction, and negative in the $y$ direction, hence it's a saddle point.

Comment: Thank you! This is well explained

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to proceed without derivatives. Note that if a function is concave, then the function restricted to any line is also concave. Similarly with convex.

The contrapositive of the above is that if there is a line such that the restriction of $f$ to it is not concave/convex, then the function is also not concave/convex.

The restriction of $f$ to the vertical line $x=0$ is  $-2e^y$, which is not convex. Thus $f$ is not convex. Also, the restriction of $f$ to $y=0$ is  $x^2 -2$ which is not concave. Thus $f$ is neither convex nor concave.
A graphical depiction on [math3d](https://www.math3d.org/AsP2xBHJ):
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are two things going on in your question: The first is that your calculation of derivatives for multivariable functions does not make sense; this is explained in the other answers.

The second thing is the question whether a function can be convex or concave only for certain parts of its domain. To illustrate, let me go to a one-variable example, say $f(x) = \sin x$. The second derivative is $- \sin x$ and hence positive for $x \in \cdots (-\pi, 0) \cup (\pi, 2\pi) \cup (3 \pi, 4 \pi) \cup (5\pi, 6\pi) \cup \cdots$. From this, you can conclude that $f$ is concave on each convex subset of this union (in this one-dimensional setting, the convex subsets are just the subintervals). So for example, $f$ is concave on $(\pi, 2\pi)$. It is not really concave on $(\pi, 2\pi) \cup (3\pi, 4\pi)$ because this set is not convex and the question “is a function concave (or convex) on a set” only makes sense when the set in questions in convex.

Convexity or concavity of a function is always relative to some convex subset of its domain. If no such set is given, we implicitly mean the entire domain of $f$. For $f$ to be concave then means that its second derivative is negative (well, non-positive) on its *entire* domain (provided $f$ is sufficiently differentiable). If the second derivative is sometimes positive and sometimes negative then specifying the subsets on which it is concave is a more precise answer, but claiming that $f$ is neither convex nor concave is technically correct.

(But also note that in the case of the function from the question, the Hessian is simply indefinite everywhere, so there is no hope for convexity or concavity at all.)